# How can I get rid of specific parenthesis without losing their contents?

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to get rid of the parentheses for params(#) in a long string with gsub in R.

From:

```
"(Prot) = ((1-(BTZ)^params(9)/((BTZ)^params(9)+params(10)^params(9))*(1+params(10)^params(9)))-(Prot)) / params(8)"
```

to get the result of:

```
"(Prot) = ((1-(BTZ)^params9/((BTZ)^params9+params10^params9)*(1+params10^params9))-(Prot)) / params8"
```

But I cannot get the right number out of the parentheses. I tried this:

```
gsub( "params\\(\\d\\)" ,'params\\d', j , fixed = FALSE)
```

This is what i got:

```
"(Prot) = ((1-(BTZ)^paramsd/((BTZ)^paramsd+params(10)^paramsd)*(1+params(10)^paramsd))-(Prot)) / paramsd;"
```

Comment: So a) you want to keep the numbers but just strip the parentheses out, and b) you want it to work for 2-digit numbers as well as 1-digit numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a capture group in your `pattern` using `()` and a reference to the capture group in `replacement` using `\\1`:

```r
gsub("\\((\\d+)\\)", "\\1", j)

#### OUTPUT ####
"(Prot) = ((1-(BTZ)^params9/((BTZ)^params9+params10^params9)*(1+params10^params9))-(Prot)) / params8"
```

I've also included `+` for cases where there's more than one digit (e.g. "10").